# In Aptana Studio 3, remove CTRL+/ binding from "comment selection"

Tags: aptana

Is there a way to remove the `CTRL+/` binding from the "comment selection" command? It doesn't appear in the *Keys* list when I filter for `CTRL+/`.

After years in Emacs with `CTRL+/` bound to 'undo' it's well and truly hard-wired in my brain. Of course I can bind `CTRL+/` to 'undo' or 'undo+', but I get an annoying command selection dialog every time I use that binding.

`KEYS: Emacs+ Scheme`
`VER : Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.0.3.201107141425`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command binding for commenting is controlled through the scripting system. You'll need to edit the "Source" bundle to change it:

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Modifying+your+shortcut+keys#Modifyingyourshortcutkeys-Instructions%28RublebasedCommands%29